# Android : flowlayout inner button with close icon onclick event

Tags: android, flowlayout

I have a requirement to create a button with close icon like as below:

[image]

i have use button and i have fatch problem when i click on button remove button.

but my requirement is onclick close icon when remove form list.

so please help me which control use so my problem solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will solved your problem

```
buttondelete.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;


            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (buttondelete.getRight() - buttondelete.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    // your action here

                 return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Voted for useful.. Thanks.. I think this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

i would add to flow layout customLaout which contains of grey background and linear layout with 2 elements inside. TextView and ImageView.

Both has own ClickListeners

something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Example Text"
        android:id="@+id/buttonTextView"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/buttonExitIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image_source"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and add Click listeners for both imageView and TextView

Answer (score 0):

```
{
     RelativeLayout mainView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
     View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null);
     Button bt_close = (Button)child.findviewById(R.id.btnclose);
     bt_put.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           RelativeLayout pView = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();
           mainView.removeView(pView); 
        }
    });
     mainView.addView(child);
 }
```

1. Create a child.xml using the RelativeLayout with childs (TextView for text and Button as Remove button)
2. Inflate the xml layout , add each views into your main_layout and 
   setonclicklistner to button.
3. when clicked on button , get the parent view from the clicked view and remove the view from main_layout.

this may help you.